# Android 5.0: Create link in internal storage to SD Card

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, external-sd, lg-g3

I have a LG G3 which I have repaired many times (actually by putting it into the furnace xD). Now I'm scared that my phone dies so I do a Titanium and Nandroid Backup every day, but none of these is backing up up my internal storage with my WhatsApp Photos and so on.

Now I had the idea to replace the WhatsApp folder with a link to my SD Card. I have root and tested it with `ln -s /storage/external_SD/test/ /sdcard/test`.
It returned `ln: /sdcard/test: Function not implemented`.

After some research I found out that links are not supported by the file system of the internal storage (I also tried to make a link to the /data/data folder and it worked so it has to be that).

My questions now:

- Is is somehow possible to make a link in the internal storage to the SD Card (e.g. with an Xposed module which emulates a link or something like that)
- Is there a better way of backing up my internal storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app called "Link2SD" on Google play store.
Link2SD uses a secondary partition on your SD card and uses it as another segment of internal storage.
Link2SD moves apk, dalvik-cache (.dex), lib and internal data files into this partition, which the OS mounts on boot, and creates a symbolic link in the original location.
This retains the file structure that the system expects but with the bulk of the data moved to the SD card.

Linking obb and external data folders of apps and games
- root permission
-Second partition on SD card is optional, folders can be moved to the 1st or 2nd second partition of the SD card.
Hope this works for u :)